# Is there one word that includes walls/ceiling/floor?

Tags: word-request

Is there one word that includes walls, ceiling, floor - basically all the faces of a building?

For example I would like to use such a word in the following sentence:

> "All the X  of this building are made of wood".

Answer (score 4):

Well there isn't any one word that is totally right.

You could argue that *surfaces* is right,

> All the **surfaces** in this building are made of wood.

You could argue that just *walls* could means walls, ceiling and floor.

> All the **walls** in this building are made of wood.

Or maybe you could say:

> All the **structure** of this building is wood.

But really there are quite a bit of words you could use and it's kind of personal preference.

Comment: I feel like these are all not quite right. "surfaces" would imply also the tables/countertops/desks/etc. are all wood. I would always assume walls only means walls, and "structure" would make me think of only structural elements (the frame or "bones" of the building, not the actual walls/ceiling/floors). I don't have a better solution though.

Comment: "**Surfaces of the building**" would remove the ambiguity you're worried about.  However the phrase would also include the roof, which is not a "face" of the building. "**Surfaces of a room**" are the walls, ceiling, and floor.

Comment: Interior designers talk about **interior surfaces**.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to refer to what is *inside* the walls, ceiling and floor, you can use **framing**.

> The framing of this house is all wood.

While there is no single word that includes the surface, you express this by saying

> This house is all steel framing covered with drywall.

Answer (score 1):

There is no English word to cover this. As has been suggested, structural surfaces is as good as anything.

Comment: "Interior Surfaces", may be a bit more apt.

Comment: As a Structural Engineer, I don't think "structural surfaces" *is* much good. "Structural" can mean "related to a structure" or it can mean "load-bearing". The latter seems more common to me (though that might be because of my job!) - if I heard someone talking about a "structural surface" I might think they meant it was loadbearing, which would be very unusual.

Comment: In computer science, walls, ceilings and floors are known as 'static geometry'